# calculate md5 of image loaded in java webdriver

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, webdriver

I want calculate md5 of images that loaded in webdriver in java.
webdriver is Firefox.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;


String script = "var imgElement = document.querySelector('div.mtl:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > img:nth-child(1))'; *** return md5 of image *** ";
String url = "http://www.facebook.com";

WebDriver webDriver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get(url);
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Stgin md5 = (String) js.executeScript(script);
```

in this code, what must replace with :

> *** return md5 of image ***

Comment: Do you want MD5 of the **image element** in DOM? Or do you want the MD5 of the image file?

Comment: I want MD5 of the image file

Comment: I think you need to use Java to download the file and then MD5 the content.

Comment: I want use from driver cache. it downloaded when i call get method. 
I don't want download again the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fetch` with `force-cache` to get the content from cache. Then digest the arrayBuffer from the response. Unfortunately, MD5 is too old and the browser doesn't support it anymore. See more details about Crypto [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest). You can choose SHA-1, SHA-256, SHA-384, and SHA-512. See an example to digest SHA-256 below.

```
public void getImageSHA256(){
    driver.get("https://www.blognone.com/");        
    WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img"));
    String imgUrl = img.getAttribute("src").trim();
    String script = "function hex(buffer) {  var hexCodes = [];  var view = new DataView(buffer);  for (var i = 0; i < view.byteLength; i += 4) { var value = view.getUint32(i); var stringValue = value.toString(16); var padding = '00000000'; var paddedValue = (padding + stringValue).slice(-padding.length); hexCodes.push(paddedValue);  }  return hexCodes.join(\"\");}" +
    "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];" + 
    "fetch(arguments[0],{cache:'force-cache'}).then((response)=> {" +
        "return response.arrayBuffer(); }).then((buffer)=>{" +
            " return crypto.subtle.digest('SHA-256', buffer); }).then((hashArray)=>{" + 
                " callback(hex(hashArray));"+
                "});";
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(script, imgUrl);
    System.out.println(response);
}
```

Screenshot below show comparison between SHA-256 from my code and SHA-256 from an online tool.
[image: Results comparison]

Comment: Thanks. can I save response into file and saw correct image? how?

Comment: @user2581337 I think you have to calculate MD5 in the JavaScript. The data in `Object response` in Java will be incorrect because of parsing and casting.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you help me for MD5 in javascript?

Comment: @user2581337 I've updated my answer to digest the image in JavaScript with SHA-256 algorithm. Unfortunately, MD5 is too old and web browsers don't support ti anymore.

Comment: can i retrieve byte array of that in java?

Comment: can I use from this script in java?

String script1 = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"
                + "fetch(' "imgUrl" ',{cache:'force-cache'})."
                + "then((response)=>{return response.arrayBuffer()}).then((response)=> {return new DataView(response)}).then((response)=> {var decoder = new TextDecoder('utf-8');"
                + "return decoder.decode(response); })."
                + "then((response)=>{callback(response)});";

Comment: @user2581337 Sorry, I don't understand your question. The `String script1=...` is JavaScript code that will be executed by Selenium. What do you mean by 'can I use...'?

Comment: Thanks. I found solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void getImageMD5(){
    driver.get("https://www.blognone.com/");        
    WebElement img = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("img"));
    String imgUrl = img.getAttribute("src").trim();
    String script = "var callback = arguments[arguments.length - 1];"
                + "function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {"
                + "    var binary = '';"
                + "    var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );"
                + "    var len = bytes.byteLength;"
                + "    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {"
                + "        binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );"
                + "    }"
                + "    return window.btoa( binary );"
                + "}"
                + " fetch(' " + imgUrl + " ',{cache:'force-cache'})."
                + "then((response)=>{return response.arrayBuffer()})."
                + "then((response)=>{return _arrayBufferToBase64(response)})."
                + "then((response)=>{callback(response)});";
    driver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Object response = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeAsyncScript(script, imgUrl);
            byte[] data = Base64.getDecoder().decode((String) response);
    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] hash = md.digest(data);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(2 * hash.length);
    for (byte b : hash) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02x", b & 0xff));
    }

    String digest = sb.toString();
    System.out.println("MD5 of Image : " + digest);
}
```

Comment: this method don't fetch image url that out of www.blognone.com domain. how can I do it?